# XSLT: adding namespaces correctly

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a SOAP Response from one of the processing rules as:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <NS1:functionResponse>
            <NS1:functionResponse>
                <functionReturn>
                    <responseCall>
                        <response />
                        <success />
                        <errorDesc/>
                    </responseCall>
                </functionReturn>
            </NS1:functionResponse>
        </NS1:functionResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And I want to convert this to the below using XSLT.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsq:functionResponse xmlns:wsq="http://service.test.com">
         <functionReturn>
            <responseCall>
                        <response />
                        <success />
                        <errorDesc/>
            </responseCall>
         </functionReturn>
      </wsq:functionResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can someone suggest a way to achieve this?

Note: With a few XSL transformations I have tried I am getting 'The prefix "SOAP-ENV" for element "SOAP-ENV:Envelope" is not bound.'

Comment: That's not really the response you are getting, is it? Because that's not a valid XML document (for the reason stated in your error message), and you won't be able to apply **any** XSL transformation to it.

Comment: Yes, that was the XML created by one of the WTX maps deployed on DataPower. I wanted to understand if it was possible to somehow transform this request to add the missing namespaces. link for my WTX question on related issue: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902167/ibm-wtx-adding-metadata-name-spaces-to-type-tree-create-from-wsdl]

Comment: *"I wanted to understand if it was possible to somehow transform this request to add the missing namespaces.*" Not through XSLT. Document must be parsed before it can be transformed; the error you see comes from the parser.